# how to use eval function to get data from string array

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, telerik, eval

I have listview and String array datasource. How can I bind them using eval ?

```
 <telerik:RadListView ID="lvDevSampTableSelection" runat="server" AllowMultiItemSelection="true">

    <ItemTemplate>
              <p><%# Eval("??") %></p>
    </ItemTemplate>

  </telerik:RadListView>
```

here is code behind

```
            ResultDto<String[]> result = client.GetTableNames("IMAPPUSER");

            var source = new BindingSource();
            source.DataSource = result.Data;

            lvDevSampTableSelection.DataSource = source;
            lvDevSampTableSelection.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `<%# Container.DataItem %>` instead of `eval` and get data from string to listview

Comment: Good point, but it will not help for anything more complex of a scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, it needs to evaluate field names from the object that is the datasource (be it columns in datatable or fields in some List). Thus, I think your best option is to create a custom class with a couple of fields, create a List<> from that class and bind to that list.